# Asynchronously showing Stored Procedure PRINT statements within .NET Web Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, asynchronous

I've written a long stored procedure that I'm calling from an ASP.NET (3.5) page.

The stored procedure looks something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE csi_CourseEval_Export
   @year
   @term
   @use_case
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   PRINT 'Building candidate course list'
   .... -- do stuff
   PRINT ''
   RAISERROR('1', '0', 1) WITH NOWAIT -- flush buffer and indicate step 1 reached
   PRINT ''
   .... -- do more stuff
   PRINT ''
   RAISERROR('2', '0', 1) WITH NOWAIT -- flush buffer and indicate step 2 reached
   PRINT ''
   .... -- do more stuff
   PRINT ''
   RAISERROR('3', '0', 1) WITH NOWAIT -- flush buffer and indicate step 3 reached
   PRINT ''
   .... -- do more stuff
   .... -- do LOTS more stuff, including steps 4 through 8
   PRINT ''
   RAISERROR('9', '0', 1) WITH NOWAIT -- flush buffer and indicate step 9 reached
   PRINT ''       

   RAISERROR('DONE', '0', 1) WITH NOWAIT -- flush buffer and indicate completion

END
```

And my C# codebehind has the following properties and methods that are relevant:

```
    private SqlConnection db;
    private string exportState = "";
    private static string jdbConnectionString = "Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=...;Persist Security Info=True;Asynchronous Processing=true;User ID=...;Password=...";

    private void ShowData(GridView display, string table)
    {
        display.DataSource = new SqlDataSource(CoursEval.jdbConnectionString, "SELECT * FROM ##" + table);
        display.DataBind();
    }

    private void SetControls(bool enable)
    {
        RunExport.Enabled = enable;

        if (enable)
            RunExport.Text = "Run";
        else
            RunExport.Text = "Running";

        UseCase.Enabled = enable;
        Year.Enabled = enable;
        Term.Enabled = enable;
    }

    private void LogSQL(string message)
    {
        if (message.Length == 1 || message.Equals("DONE"))
        {
            exportState = message;
        }
        SQL_Log.Text += "<br />" + message.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;").Replace("\n", "<br />");
    }

    protected void RunExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db = new SqlConnection(jdbConnectionString);

        db.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;            
        db.InfoMessage += delegate(object ds, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs de)
        {
            LogSQL(de.Message);              
        };
        db.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("csi_CourseEval_Export", db);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Year.SelectedValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@term", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Term.SelectedValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@use_case", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UseCase.SelectedValue;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

        SetControls(false);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        ShowData(ShowCourses, "Courses");
        ShowData(ShowStudents, "Students");
        ShowData(ShowFaculty, "Faculty");

        ResultsPanel.Visible = true;

        db.Close();
        SetControls(true);
    }
```

The following `System.Web.UI.WebControls.*` form objects are relevant:

```
SQL_Log                                - Label
RunExport                              - Button
UseCase, Year and Term                 - DropDownList 
ShowCourses, ShowFaculty, ShowStudent  - GridView
ResultsPanel                           - Panel
```

The symptom:
no matter what I do, the `SQL_Log` label only updates once, at the very end of the stored procedure, while everything else is showing up.

The desired behavior:
`SQL_Log` label should update asynchronously, letting the user see how far along the stored procedure has come.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
This is a partial answer:

Updating to use asynchronous SqlCommand (BeginExecuteNonQuery onstead of ExecuteNonQuery) gets me to the first RAISERROR, but then I don't receive any further InfoMessage events after EndExecuteNonQuery is called, even though the Stored Procedure is still running at that point.

RunExport_Click now looks like:

```
    protected void RunExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db = new SqlConnection(CoursEval.jdbConnectionString);

        db.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;            
        db.InfoMessage += delegate(object ds, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs de)
        {
            LogSQL(de.Message);              
        };
        db.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("csi_CourseEval_Export", db);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Year.SelectedValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@term", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Term.SelectedValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@use_case", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UseCase.SelectedValue;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.StatementCompleted += GetExportResults;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

        SetControls(false);

        cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery(new AsyncCallback(FinishExport), cmd);

    }
```

And I now have three additional functions, ShowResults, GetExportResults and FinishExport:

```
    private void ShowResults()
    {
        ShowData(ShowCourses, "Courses");
        ShowData(ShowFaculty, "Faculty");
        ShowData(ShowFacultyEnrollment, "FacultyEnrollment");
        ShowData(ShowStudents, "Students");
        ShowData(ShowStudentEnrollment, "StudentEnrollment");

        ResultsPanel.Visible = true;

    }


    private void FinishExport(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        if (result.IsCompleted)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = (SqlCommand)result.AsyncState;

            cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);
        }
        else
        {
            RunExport.Text = exportState;
        }
    }

    private void GetExportResults(object sender, StatementCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowResults();

        db.Close();
        SetControls(true);
    }
```

Additionally, LogSQL now looks like this:

```
    private void LogSQL(string message)
    {
        if (message.Length == 1 || message.Equals("DONE"))
        {
            exportState = message;
        }

        SQL_Log.Text += "<br />" + message.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;").Replace("\n", "<br />");
        ProgressPanel.Update();
    }
```

where ProgressPanel is the AJAX-driven UpdatePanel that everything is loaded within.

The script now reaches the stage 2 RAISERROR, at which point FinishExport fires and I receive no further InfoMessage events. GetExportResults never fires, so the whole page basically hangs at that point. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to update a label asynchronously - web applications don't work that way. When your page executes, it sends HTML to the browser, and then is destroyed. There is no simple process by which you can continue to send updated HTML to the browser.

Comment: Untrue - everything is inside an UpdatePanel with ChildrenAsTriggers = true, so it's all using AJAX.

Comment: Doesn't matter at all. That would help, but there's nothing to trigger the update. It's all just happening during a single request.

Comment: Shouldn't the Update be triggered whenever SQL_Log.Text is changed?

EDIT: If I put ProgressPanel.Update(); as the next line after SQL_Log.Text +=..., it still doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: No. All of the execution of the SP takes place in the first request. There is no opportunity for an UpdatePanel trigger.

Comment: So, updating to use asynchronous SqlCommand (BeginExecuteNonQuery onstead of ExecuteNonQuery) gets me to the first RAISERROR, but then I don't receive any further InfoMessage events after EndExecuteNonQuery is called, even though the Stored Procedure is still running at that point.

Comment: Suggestion: give up this entire idea. You should not be performing long-running operations from an ASP.NET page at all. If that's necessary, then they should be run in a WCF service, and the display should be updated by polling the service for progress. In fact, I question that it makes any sense to show the user the actual progress: what's the user going to _do_ about it? Just show a spinner, or just show "I started this, it will be finished eventually"

Comment: The eventual goal is to capture the "1" through "9" RAISERRORS and use them to drive a progress bar.

Comment: Again, I consider this to be a bad idea. Among other things, to have a stored procedure driving user interface seems like an overlap of responsibilities. And, again, ask yourself what the user is going to _do_ with this information, other than critique your because it takes so long.

Comment: Ideally, the user will use the information to stop asking me "are you sure it's still running?"

Comment: No, they'll begin asking you why it's still running so slowly. This is why spinners or "loading" animations are used so frequently. It makes the user believe that something is happening. Do you really need to make the user wait until the entire SP is finished? Maybe just tell them it has started, and will finish as soon as possible. Do they even need to know that it takes a long time?

Comment: We're now getting pretty far off topic, but here's the basic problem:

The export stored procedure can handle a lot of different Use Cases. Some Use Cases have to process and return a few dozen records. Some Use Cases have to process and return a few tens of thousands of records. Some Use Cases will only have to process a few records if 1998 is selected, but have to process thousands if 2013 is selected. 

There's not really a good way for the user to tell whether it's having to go through hundreds of thousands of records or just a few dozen without running it.

Comment: I recommend using a pattern where the stored procedure stores progress data in the database itself. Other code (the web page) can query the database. I bet your users don't usually want to sit there on the page watching the progress bar - they'd probably prefer to check back from time to time. You could even store richer data, like row counts, and not just progress bars.